# Search and Play Youtube videos in android

Tags: android, gridview, video, youtube

I'm building an application in which i want to search for videos related to a keyword like "World Cup 2014". and then a GridView showing the videos appears (Like in Search Result Screen) and when user clicks on any video(gridview item), particular video plays in next screen(Video Playing Screen).
[image]

Please suggest can I search using Youtube Android Player API? Or I will have to use Youtube Data API before playing the video using Youtube Android Player API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use Youtube Data API and then play video using Youtube Player API

Answer (score 0):

You may check this open source code, maybe it will help you understand how to search/play video. It's using JSON.

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java